# Is it possible to retrieve the list of files when a DataFrame is written, or or have spark store it somewhere?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

With a call like 
`df.write.csv("s3a://mybucket/mytable")`
I obviously know where files/objects are written, but because of S3's eventual consistency guarantees, I can't be 100% sure that getting a listing from that location will return all (or even any) of the files that were just written.  If I could get the list of files/objects spark just wrote, then I could prepare a manifest file for a Redshift COPY command without worrying about eventual consistency.  Is this possible-- and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

The `spark-redshift` library can take care of this for you. If you want to do it yourself you can have a look at how they do it here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/1092c7cd03bb751ba4e93b92cd7e04cffff10eb0/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftWriter.scala#L299

EDIT: I avoid further worry about consistency by using `df.coalesce(fileCount)` to output a known number of file parts (for Redshift you want a multiple of the slices in your cluster). You can then check how many files are listed in the Spark code and also how many files are loaded in Redshift `stl_load_commits`.

Comment: That's still calling FileSystem.listStatus(), so vulnerable to S3 list inconsistency.

Comment: Note added about using `coalesce()` to output a known file count

Comment: Worrying that the spark-redshift library chooses to ignore the problem, but some interesting workarounds.  It feels like Spark should really have a feature to be able to write a manifest out-- to a single file via the driver, not a directory from the workers; that would solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to be aware of consistency risks; you can get it in listings with delayed create visibility and deleted objects still being found.

AFAIK, You can't get a list of files created, as its somewhere where tasks can generate whatever they want into the task output dir, which is then marshalled (via listing and copy) into the final output dir,

In the absence of a consistency layer atop S3 (S3mper, s3guard, etc), you can read & spin for "a bit" to allow for the shards to catch up. I have no good idea of what is a good value of "a bit".

However, if you are calling `fs.write.csv()`, you may have been caught by listing inconsistencies within the committer used to propagate task output to the job dir; s that's done in S3A via list + copy, see.

Comment: why the - votes? What have I got wrong? I'll correct it if I'm told the details.

Comment: I don't know why you got the downvote, you provided a lot of good information about consistency layers I had no idea existed (I was only aware of EMRFS).  On your last sentence though it looks like you ended mid-sentence.